# How to find Time complexity of merge sort with parameter?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, mergesort

```
public static void MergeSort(int[] a, int p) {
  MergeSort(a, 0, a.length - 1, p);
}
private static void MergeSort(int[] a, int start, int end, int p) {
  if (end - start > 0) {
    int middle = (start + end) / 2;
    MergeSort(a, start, middle, p);
    MergeSort(a, middle + 1, end, p);
    Merge(a, start, middle, end, p);
  }
}
private static void Merge(int[] a, int start, int middle, int end, int p) {
  int[] b = new int[Math.min(end - start + 1, p)];
  int i = start, j = middle + 1, k = 0;
  while (i <= middle && j <= end && k < p)
    if (a[i] < a[j]) b[k++] = a[i++];
    else b[k++] = a[j++];
  while (i < middle && k < p)
    b[k++] = a[i++];
  while (j <= end && k < p)
    b[k++] = a[j++];
  for (k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
    a[start + k] = b[k];
}
```

I need to Find Time complexity  of ***MergeSort*** ?

the time complexity of ***Merge*** is **O(min (p,n))** ,so the time complexity of   ***MergeSort***  is **O(min (p,n)log(min (p,n)))**

is this correct and if not how to find the correct time complexity?

and if I want to prove that ***MergeSort*** return Array that containing the first  ***p*** elements that are the smallest and they are sorting ?

thanks.

Comment: "the time complexity of Merge is O(min (p,n)) ,so the time complexity of MergeSort is O(min (p,n)log(min (p,n)))" -- what's your reasoning for that?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: @Raphael because we send to Merge Arry with length  n/(2^k) but it return array with min(p,n) elements so we get log(min(p/2^k,n/2^k)) merge that for every one of it the time complexity min(p,n)